# Intrinsic c++ vs2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sse, simd, intrinsics

During playing around with intrinsics , after switching to x64 build, compiler showed error message:

```
C3861   '_mm_hadds_pi16': identifier not found
```

So I've checked inside a file tmminitrin.h

```
#if defined(_M_IX86)
    extern __m64 _mm_hadd_pi16 (__m64, __m64);
    extern __m64 _mm_hadd_pi32 (__m64, __m64);
    extern __m64 _mm_hadds_pi16 (__m64, __m64);
#endif
```

`_M_IX86` is not defined in x64 build

I'm confused because [in msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531432(v=vs.120).aspx) in requirements section it says Architecture x86,x64.

Why in x64 build I'm prevented from using all intrinsics that takes `__m64` as parameters and return `__m64`?

Second question: Is `_mm_hadds_pi16()` faster or slower than `_mm_hadds_epi16()` or is it processor specific?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32446304/253056

Comment: Documentation bug, can only work on x86 since it uses MMX registers.  You need the epi16 flavor if you want to target x64.