# What does the "P" prefix stand for in the x86 instruction PCLMULQDQ?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, sse, instruction-set

In the Carry-less Multiplication x86 instruction, `PCLMULQDQ`, what does the "P" prefix stand for?

I've looked in these sources, but none of them explain the mnemonics.

- https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=clmul
- https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pclmulqdq
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLMUL_instruction_set

Secondly, what does "QDQ" stand for?

Comment: P = packed. [SIMD integer instructions begin with P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions#Integer_instructions), or VP if they use the new VEX/EVEX encoding. Floating-point instructions [end with PS/PD...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions#Floating-point_instructions) where P is also packed

Comment: Packed Carry-Less MULtiply Quadwords to Double Quadwords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**P is for Packed (integer).**  All SSE/AVX integer instructions have mnemonics starting with `p`, like `paddb`.  (Or `vp` for the AVX versions).  As opposed to `...ps` (packed-single) and `...pd` packed-double instructions.

Q for Quad-word (64-bit) chunks of the source operand multiplying into a double-quad (128-bit) integer.

---

**Related:**

- [What comes after QWORD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645078/what-comes-after-qword) including meaning of mnemonics like `punpcklqdq` as an example of where `dq` is used instead of `o` (octword like scalar `cqo`), for interleaving 64-bit chunks to make a 128-bit, following the same pattern as `punpcklwd` (16 bit interleave).
- [How can Microsoft say the size of a word in WinAPI is 16 bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308438/how-can-microsoft-say-the-size-of-a-word-in-winapi-is-16-bits) the 8086 history of "word" being 16-bit in x86, not rewriting the documentation for 386 or x86-64.  It gets baked into many mnemonics like scalar `cbw` as well as SIMD element sizes.
- [What's the size of a QWORD on a 64-bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430725/whats-the-size-of-a-qword-on-a-64-bit-machine) (the terminology depends on the ISA.)
- [What are the names and meanings of the intrinsic vector element types, like epi64x or pi32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70911872/what-are-the-names-and-meanings-of-the-intrinsic-vector-element-types-like-epi6) focuses on intrinsic names, not asm mnemonics.
- [Meaning of suffix "x" in intrinsics like "_mm256_set1_epi64x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989391/meaning-of-suffix-x-in-intrinsics-like-mm256-set1-epi64x) - more intrinsics stuff.