# GCC throwing an error while clang works fine while using _mm512_permutevar_epi32

Tags: c++, gcc, intrinsics, gcc-warning, avx512

I am getting this error from the GCC compiler -

> error: there are no arguments to ‘_mm512_permutevar_epi32’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘_mm512_permutevar_epi32’ must be available [-fpermissive]

```
rev = _mm512_permutevar_epi32(_mm512_setr_epi32(15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0), elem);
```

The code compiles fine with clang. I have included the immintrin.h and x86intrin.h.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be a `_mm512_permutevar_epi32` intrinsic, never use it.

**Use the `_mm512_permutexvar_epi32` intrinsic for the `vpermd` instruction.**

[Intel documents it in their intrinsics guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE_ALL,AVX_ALL,AVX_512,Other&ig_expand=840,4998,6237,6267,5912,2574,6094&text=vpermd), but that's bad and misleading naming.  We don't need two different intrinsics for the same form of the same instruction, especially one that doesn't follow the previous naming convention.  In some ways it's a good thing GCC doesn't provide that misnamed intrinsic for `vpermd`.  Intel's asm manual entry (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermd:vpermw) only lists the `permutexvar` intrinsics, so that's good.

The intrinsics guide documentation even says:

> This intrinsic is identical to `_mm512_permutexvar_epi32`, and it is recommended that you use that intrinsic name.

---

The naming convention has previously been that lane-crossing shuffles like `vpermd` (this one) and `vpermps` get an `x` in their name, but in-lane shuffles like `vpermilps` (`_mm512_permutevar_ps` with a vector control and `_mm512_permute_ps` with an immediate) don't.

There is no `__m512i` integer equivalent of `vpermilps vec,vec,vec`, only the immediate-control `vpshufd vec,vec,imm8` (`_mm512_shuffle_epi32`) and the lane-crossing `vpermd`, so it's misleading to name an intrinsic following the in-lane-shuffle naming pattern, especially when there *is* a difference for the `_ps` version of the same names.  (`vpermps` and `vpermilps` both exist since AVX2.)

And just in general, different names that mean the same thing add confusion and make things harder to mentally keep track of, especially when there's nothing wrong or unclear about one of them.

---

I *am* in favour of Intel's new `_mm_bslli_si128` name for `pslldq` byte-shifts, with the "b" in the name emphasizing it's *not* a bit-shift, not a 128-bit version of `_mm_slli_epi64`.  In that case I think the new name adds clarity.  And the 256 and 512-bit versions reflect the in-lane nature with `_mm256_bslli_epi128` instead of `si128`, which is unusual but maybe a good reminder.

Unlike here where the non-`x` name *removes* clarity.  Perhaps someone at Intel made the mistake of adding the non-`x` name first?  And somehow they didn't catch that before release, since I assume both names were added to the guide at the same time in this case (since it would be weird if GCC only supported the newer one), unlike the `bslli` case where that new name came much later.

Or maybe the `permutevar` name for `vpermd` did make it into an early publication before hardware was released and before GCC added support for either, or GCC devs caught the inconsistency themselves and brought it to Intel's attention, since Intel's docs now do recommend against using it.

This naming weirdness is also somewhat similar to the case of *[error: '_mm512_loadu_epi64' was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604986/error-mm512-loadu-epi64-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)* where Intel introduced redundant intrinsics for non-masking loads.  The 128 and 256-bit versions do let you use `void*` instead of having to `_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)&arr[i])`, but with the downside of being very easy to confuse with intrinsics for `movd` and `movq` narrow loads (`_mm_loadu_si32`).

Comment: The misnaming might be connected with `x` removal in [`*_set_epi64`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=set_epi64) . `__mm512_set_epi64` doesn't have the annoying `x` anymore. The error then acknowledged: _This intrinsic is identical to `_mm512_permutexvar_epi32`, and it is recommended that you use that intrinsic name_, says the Guide

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: Thanks for pointing out that the intrinsics guide entry itself recommends the other name, I hadn't noticed that.  But this `x` is in a different place from the `epi64x`, which has/had a different meaning (to disambiguate MMX vs. x86-64 SSE2: *[Meaning of suffix "x" in intrinsics like "\_mm256\_set1\_epi64x"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44989391)* - `_mm_set_epi64` takes two `__m64` args, not `int64_t`.  They followed the naming pattern for `_mm256_set_epi64x` even though there was no `_mm256_set_epi64`.  So yes it's "annoying", but totally different meaning than `permutex`)